# Submit form to new tab and close it right away

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I have a form with "target" set to "_blank" in order to open a new tab when the form is submitted. The action of this form is an aspx page that does server-side processing and returns an html. I am trying to figure out whether it's possible to close the new browser tab right away without waiting for the returned html.

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `window.close()` property that comes with the browser API. Not sure how you're setting up your server-side processing, but you can listen for an event on that browser tab and fire off the `window.close()` when the HTML is returned from your server.

Combining this with the onLoad event, you should be able to pull this off:

```
window.addEventListener('load', e => {
    window.close();
});
```

Comment: I want to close the tab right ater it was opened without waiting for html to return. Another words, all I want is to just to kick out a server-side process. I will also change its return. Instead of html it will push a file back.

Comment: Not sure why you need a new tab for the server-side process if you don't care about what it returns. Can you share snippets of your code and speak more of your intentions here?

Comment: Yes, good question. Currently the form is submitted with a target of an iframe placed on the same screen. Server process is taking much longer now and we want to use newtab so the user can navigate to other parts of app. Yes, he can do it even without opening a tab, story though.. I want to close new tab automatically after the file created on the server is downloaded. Easy to do when the server send an hrml back that actually down the file. But I am thinking to stream the file back to Browser - no html to return. In this case it is much harder to close the tab after the download completes.